# Bitwise XOR operator to find missing unique ID

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have an array with positive integers. All except one element in this array doesn't have a duplicate. The way to find the unique element is by using the XOR bitwise operator which returns 1 only if one of the element is 1 and false otherwise.

Following is the code:

```
public class Bitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deliveryIds = {34, 40, 2, 21, 50, 40, 34, 2, 50};
        System.out.println(new Bitter().findUniqueDeliveryId(deliveryIds));
    }

    public int findUniqueDeliveryId(int[] deliveryIds) {
        int uniqueDeliveryId = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < deliveryIds.length; i++) {
            uniqueDeliveryId ^= deliveryIds[i];
        }

        return uniqueDeliveryId;
    }

}
```

In the loop, each of the integers in the array are XORed with uniqueId starting at 0. Then, 0 is XOR'ed with 34. The result is then XOR'ed with the next integer in the array 40 and we go through the entire array.

I'm still unable to understand even after setting breakpoints and going through the entire flow one line at a time, how XORing with uniqueId (starting with it's value 0) can help us find the non-duplicate integer in the array?

Shouldn't a number like 40 XOR'ed with itself (resulting in the value 0), to confirm that it's a duplicate. Unlike here, where we are XOR'ing 0 with the first integer in the array, and the result with the subsequent number in the array. What am I missing/

Comment: I think you meant to say "All except one element in this array have a duplicate."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`XOR`ing n numbers is like counting the number of 1 bits in each position, and setting the corresponding output bit to 1 if the count is odd. The order in which you are `XOR`ing them doesn't matter.

If an array contains x pairs of equal numbers and one unique number, the bits of the equal pairs cancel each other (since they contribute an even number of 1s in each position), leaving you with just the bits of the unique number.

For example, take the following list of numbers :

```
100100101
010110110
101101100 // the unique number
100100101
010110110
```

Count the number of 1s in each position:

```
321521522
```

Result of XOR (1 bit in for each odd count) :

```
101101100
```

which is the single unique number in the list.

Comment: Great explanation!!! Finally helped me to understand why this works hahaha

Answer (score 14):

Looking at it like math, rather than code; and using `^` to mean `bit-level xor`, we can say that

- xor is commutative: `A ^ B = B ^ A`
- xor is associative: `(A ^ B) ^ C = A ^ (B ^ C)`
- xoring with zero does nothing: `A ^ 0 = A`
- xoring something twice removes it: `A ^ A = 0`

The first two properties imply that any reordering of a sequence of xors will yield the exact same result.

Therefore, given a sequence that contains duplicates, they will all be removed via xor:

```
   A ^ B ^ X ^ A ^ B  =  A^A ^ B^B ^ X  =  0 ^ 0 ^ X   =  X
                      \ reorder         \ xoring twice \ removing zeroes
```

Note that this trick only works if there is a single element that is not duplicate. If there were several, the result would be the XOR of all non-evenly-duplicated elements:

```
   A ^ B ^ C ^ A  =  A^A ^ B ^ C  =  B ^ C
```

Comment: I think another important property of XOR, which is required in order to understand why this works, is that it's *associative*: (A ^ B) ^ C = A ^ (B ^ C).

Comment: True, editing to reflect. I thought that one implied the other, but was able to find counter-examples: a # b = (a+b)/2 is commutative, but not associative. And without both properties, you are not free to reorder stuff. So thanks for the comment - improved answer, and learned some math.